# Select and Update statement help needed

Tags: sql, oracle, select, sql-update

**Scenario:**

I have two tables: Vendors table provides the unique identifiers; and the Order table has rows containing a column that has unique identifiers which we are want to strip.  For example: unique ID: 12345 and the the content has "Order for 12345"...desired result, literally: "Order for XXXXX"

I need a select statement to show which records from table 2 actually has the unique identifier and a update statement to do the stripping.

**Schema**

```
Table Vendors
    ID   varchar2(9)
    NAME varchar(50)

Table Orders
    OrderNumber varchar2(10)
    Dscr        varchar(250) <----order description
```

**Sample:**

```
Vendors
12345 Joe
23456 Jenni

Orders
A123456 | Order for 12345 <---notice this number is the ID of the Vendor
B039483 | Order for 23456
```

**Desired Result:**

```
Orders 
    A123456 | Order for XXXXX
    B039483 | Order for XXXXX
```

**What I have so far:**

```
DECLARE  
  TYPE dscr_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(250);
  chk_dscr_coll dscr_type;

BEGIN 
  -- gather a list of IDs to use
  FOR someone IN (
    SELECT unique(ID) FROM vendors WHERE TIN IS NOT NULL
  )

  -- loop through the Orders table
  -- try to match the ID agains each record via regular expression

  LOOP
    SELECT dscr BULK COLLECT INTO dscr_coll
    FROM orders
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(dscr, '.*'||someone.ID||'.*');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>'||dscr_coll(1));

  END LOOP;
  EXCEPTION 
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('');
END;
/
```

**UPDATE**

I follow a lead provided by Kordirko and came up with this MERGE statement.

```
MERGE INTO AFMOWN.ABS_DOC_ACTG target
USING (
   SELECT v.TIN 
   FROM AFMOWN.R_VEND_CUST v
   where v.TIN is not null
) vendor
ON (chk_dscr LIKE '%' || vendor.TIN || '%')
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET chk_dscr = REGEXP_REPLACE( chk_dscr, vendor.TIN, '999999999' );
```

Unfortunately, I got this error:
LHS of UPDATE SET contains the columns referenced in the ON Clause

Can someone help?

Comment: I dont have idea what you want. Show us db schema, sample data and expected result. You do a lot of things on that store procedure doesnt make sense.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try MERGE statement:

```
MERGE INTO Orders
USING (
   SELECT v.id FROM Vendor v
   JOIN Orders o
   ON v.descr LIKE '%' || v.id || '%'
) x
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
SET descr = REPLACE( descr, x.id, 'XXXXX" )
;
```

Comment: not sure if this work for MSSQL or MySQL, but it doesn't work for Oracle but the use of MERGE is a good lead.  I am still playing with it.

Comment: I just tried MERGE in Oracle, but it's not working in my scenario, because DSCR is used in the ON clause, so it cannot be updated.

Comment: I am marking this as the solution, because MERGE INTO is the right approach.  Though statement provided in this answer is not syntactically correct, but the approach is.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PL/SQL code for this. Assuming the order numbers need to be replaced with 'XXXXX' you can do something like this:

```
update orders set dscr = regexp_replace(dscr, '\d+', 'XXXXX')
```

Comment: It's my bad that I oversimplify the scenario.  The reality is that there could be other numbers in the dscr field.